# Как указать комментарии к таблице и столбцам MySql?

Tags: база-данных, mysql

Есть структура таблицы, например, вот такая:

```
   CREATE TABLE `user_visit` (
      `visit_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `application` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
      `user_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
      `referrer` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
      `ip` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
      `date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
      `USER_AGENT` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`visit_id`),
      KEY `FK_user_user_visit` (`user_id`),
      CONSTRAINT `FK_user_user_visit` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Появилась необходимость добавить комментарии к самой таблице и к каждому столбцу (работа в команде все дела).

Но, к сожалению, я не нашел синтаксиса, как добавить комментарии к столбцам и таблице в MySql. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE `my_super_table` (
    `my_super_column` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'My super comment'
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

**Обновление**

```
ALTER TABLE `my_super_table`
    CHANGE COLUMN `my_super_column` `my_super_column` INT NOT      NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'My super comment'
```

Comment: А добавить комментарий в уже существующий столбец через modify?

Comment: Обновил ответ

Comment: несколько часов парился правил миграции, добавляя комментарии к каждому полю. =( На что не пойдешь ради команды. Большое спасибо.

Answer (score -1):

> Как добавить комментарии к столбцам и **таблице** в MySql?

```
ALTER TABLE table-name COMMENT='....';
```

Comment: в вопросе автор спрашивает "как добавить комментарии к **столбцам** и таблице в MySql". Возможно Вам стоит расширить Ваш ответ, чтобы он отвечал на весь вопрос.